# Help with checkbox and database

Tags: php

please i want help im a begginer

I have a form with checkboxes. Each have a value when the checkboxes are checked it's value is added to the sum... I want to save the checkboxes that are checked into a database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal() {
        document.listForm.total.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
          if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseFloat(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
          }
        }
        document.listForm.total.value = sum;
    }
</script>

<form name="listForm" method="post" action="insert_options.php" >
<TABLE cellPadding=3 width=600 border=0>
        <TBODY>

        <TR>
          <TH align=left width="87%" bgColor=#b0b3b4><SPAN 
            class=whiteText>Item</SPAN></TH>
          <TH align=right width="13%" bgColor=#b0b3b4><SPAN 
            class=whiteText>Select</SPAN></TH></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#9da8af"colSpan=2><SPAN class=normalText><B>General</B></SPAN></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#c4c8ca"><SPAN class=normalText >TEAK SIDE DECKS (2889)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="2889" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" /></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>LEAD DEEP KEEL (1825)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="1825" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>FULLY BATTENED MAINSAIL (558)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="558"  type="checkbox"  onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>HIGH TECH SAILS FOR CONVENTIONAL RIG (1979)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="1979" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>IN MAST REEFING WITH HIGH TECH SAILS (2539)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="2539" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SPlNNAKER GEAR (POLE LINES DECK FITTINGS) (820)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="820" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SPINNAKER POLE VERTICAL STOWAGE SYSTEM (214)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="214" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>GAS ROD KICKER (208)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="208" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SIDE RAIL OPENINGS (BOTH SIDES) (392)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="392" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SPRING CLEATS MIDSHIPS -ALUMIMIUM (148)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="148" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>


          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>ELECTRIC ANCHOR WINDLASS (1189)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="1189" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"> </TD></TR>



          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>ANCHOR CHAIN GALVANISED (50m) (202)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="202" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"> </TD></TR>



          <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>ANCHOR CHAIN GALVANISED (50m) (1141)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="1141" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#9da8af"colSpan=2><SPAN class=normalText><B>NAVIGATION & ELECTRONICS</B></SPAN></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#c4c8ca"><SPAN class=normalText >WIND VANE (STAINLESS STEEL)(41)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="41" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" /></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>RAYMARINE ST6O LOG & DEPTH (SEPARATE UNITS)(226)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="226" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

      <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#9da8af"colSpan=2><SPAN class=normalText><B>ENGINES & ELECTRICS</B></SPAN></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SHORE SUPPLY (220V) WITH 3 OUTLETS (EXCLUDJNG SHORE CABLE) (327)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="327"  type="checkbox"  onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

        <TR>
          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>3rd BATTERY(14OA/H)(196)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="196" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

         <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>24 AMP BATTERY CHARGER (475)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="475" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>2 BLADED FOLDING PROPELLER (UPGRADE)(299)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="299" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>


         <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#9da8af"colSpan=2><SPAN class=normalText><B>BELOW DECKS/DOMESTIC</B></SPAN></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>WARM WATER (FROM ENGINE & 220V)(749)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="749" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>SHOWER IN AFT HEADS WITH PUMPOUT(446)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="446" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>DECK SUCTION DISPOSAL FOR HOLDINGTANK(166)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="166" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>REFRIGERATED COOLBOX (12V)(666)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="666" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>LFS SAFETY PACKAGE (COCKPIT HARNESS POINTS STAINLESS STEEL JACKSTAYS)(208)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="208" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>UPHOLSTERY UPGRADE IN SALOON (SUEDETYPE)(701)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="701" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
          <TD  bgcolor="#9da8af"colSpan=2><SPAN class=normalText><B>NAVIGATION ELECTRONICS & ELECTRICS</B></SPAN></TD></TR>

          <TD bgColor=#c4c8ca><SPAN class=normalText>VHF RADIO AERIAL CABLED TO NAVIGATION AREA(178)</SPAN></TD>
          <TD align=right bgColor=#c4c8ca><input  name="choice" value="178" type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()"></TD></TR>
</table>
```

and the php code is

```
<?php

$opt=serialize($_POST['choice']); //takes the data from a post operation...
$query="INSERT INTO options VALUES('$opt')"; 

?>
```

Comment: please simplify your code, remove all none necesarry HTML

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408834/retriving-saved-checkboxes-name-and-values-from-database#408899)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, all of your `<input type="checkbox">` fields have the same `name` attribute. This results in several values with the same name being sent over (if several checkboxes are checked), of which PHP only uses the last one for its `$_POST` collection.

To solve this, give them the name "`choice[]`", instead of "`choice`". This signals PHP that there are several values possible, and they will be all available as an array. In other words, you will be able to do the following:

```
$choices = $_POST['choice'];
foreach ( $choices as $key => $value )
    echo "$key  => $value";
```

And this will output something like

```
0 => 32
1 => 12
2 => 48
```

In other words - you get an array with the values of the checked checkboxes. After that you can do what you like with them. For example, `implode()` them to get a comma-separated list.

One thing that you should be warned about though. It's called "SQL Injection" and is a common mistake of inexperienced programmers. The idea is that a malicious user can easily send other values there too, not only the ones you have specified in your HTML. It does not take much skill to forge a HTTP request. There can be **ANYTHING** coming from the user, so you should **ALWAYS** check **ALL INPUT** that you get from the user. Don't trust any JavaScript validations you make. As long as it's from the user side - it cannot be trusted. Ever.

And if you are wondering how that can be a bad thing - consider, what would happen if suddenly one of the values in your array wouldn't be `43` anymore, but instead would be "**`'); DROP DATABASE; --`**".

Since you are blindly executing a query like

```
INSERT INTO options VALUES('$opt');
```

This would then turn into

```
INSERT INTO options VALUES(''); DROP DATABASE; --);
```

And bye-bye goes your database. Thus, **ALWAYS** make sure that the user input is what you expect it to be and that there is no possiblity for something like this. Oh, and yes - `addslashes()` is not a good method because there is still a way around that. Parametrized queries are the best way to go, but if you can't use that then at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL, or whatever else your DBMS offers.

Comment: Man awesome answer. you deserve more up points for this one :)